# Why does xlwings change the value of my output?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm trying to automate some work using xlwings but for some reason xlwings appends ".0" to my values SOMETIMES. Only seems to happens when my value is an integer.

I put for example 7427711 into a cell. but when i read from that cell again its now magically 7427711.0

My code looks like this:

```
import xlwings as xw

    file = xw.Book.caller()
    sheet = file.sheets[0]
    
    partnumber = 7123123

    sheet[5, 2].value = partnumber
    print(sheet[5, 2].value)
    print(partnumber)
```

OUTPUT:

```
7427711.0
7427711
```

please help me understand this. I'm new to xlwings and this is really annoying.

Comment: Please, provide [mre]

Comment: Sorry. I changed it to be as short as possible

Comment: Check https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html the section about numbers